# Calculation involving modulus and indexing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encryption

I have an image A of size s by s. All the pixel intensities A(i,j) lie between [1,s]. Now I need to shuffle the pixel intensities of A also change the intensity values in A.

For this I implement the matrix MAT and multiply with the vector `[i, j, A(i,j)]`, where `(i,j)` is the pixel index and `A(i,j)` is the pixel intensity.

The result is saved in the vectors `a`, `b`, and `c`, where `(a,b)` should be the new index and `c` should be the new intensity value.

For example

- For `s=5` and the triplet `(1,1,5)`, the result is the triplet `(3,5,3)`.
- Now I take this triplet and make a new matrix `ENC` like `ENC(3,5)=3`.
- The problem at hand is now how to get all the indexes like `(1,1)..(25,25)` for `ENC` beacuse not all indexes are coming. And how to invert all this to get back `A`.

This is my current code:

```
format compact
s=3;  
A=randi(s,s);
[s,~]=size(A);
a=zeros(1,s*s);
b=zeros(1,s*s);
c=zeros(1,s*s);
t=1;
for i=1:s
    for j=1:s
        MAT=[2 1 3;3 2 5;2 1 4];
        newcord =MAT*[i j A(i,j)]'
        a(t)= mod(newcord(1)-1,s)+1;
        b(t)= mod(newcord(2)-1,s)+1;
        c(t)= mod(newcord(3)-1,s)+1;
        t=t+1;
    end
end

ENC=zeros(s,s);
for t=1:s^2
    ENC(a(t),b(t))=c(t)
end
```

The output I currently get is

```
A = [ 3     1     3
      2     3     2
      1     2     1 ]
a = [ 3     1     2     2     3     1     1     2     3 ]
b = [ 2     3     3     3     1     1     1     2     2 ]
c = [ 3     2     2     1     3     3     2     1     1 ]
```

The output i desire is a matrix ENC that contains the new values and also from ENC i should get back A by perform the inverse of the above process.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to say what you are doing. I see a lot of code, your output and then a question. Please explain what the code is doing and why you'd want to change it the way you mention and what you have already tried to change it this way,

Comment: I have added the information

Comment: What is the output youd like?

Comment: i have mentioned it

Comment: "Shuffled and changed" is not well defined...

Comment: Please give an example of an output you'd like with its respective input

Comment: shuffled means A(1,1) should be permuted to some other index given by (a(t),b(t)) and the changed value of A(1,1) should be stored in c(t).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, using `randperm`:

```
% example data
A=11:19;A=reshape(A,3,3)';
% generate random permutation of the indices
rpind=randperm(prod(size(A)));
% just index the matrix
c=A(rpind);
% get the i,j indices of the said permutation (probably not needed as linear indices are enough)
[a,b]=ind2sub(size(A),rpind);
```

Comment: No i need this to be deterministic so that i can get back A. and also the values in c need to be changed

Comment: @Upstart the way I did it, its you can get back the values. Just run the random permutation once and store it. It does look like you are triying to come up with an ad hoc cryptography algorithm. I hope not, because you are going to fail. They are based in complex math, not trial and error.

Comment: But still this not the answer i needed, thanx

Comment: @Upstart ah, It would have been different if you would have posed the question correctly! this fits your question. I am happy to try to help you more, but clearly the question needs to be changed for that.